# Tensorflow: Setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a CNN using my own image dataset, but when passing the batch data and label to the `feed_dict` I get the error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence` from what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156639/tensorflow-python-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-in-t), this is a dimension issue, and probably coming from my `batch_label` Tensor, but I couldn't figure out how to make it a one-hot Tensor (what my graph expects).

I uploaded the full code as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/guivn/f7f753547f77a3b12992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You can't feed a `tf.Tensor` object (viz. `batch_data` and `batch_labels` in your [gist](https://gist.github.com/guivn/f7f753547f77a3b12992)) as the value for another tensor. (I believe the error message should be clearer about this in more recent versions of TensorFlow.)

Unfortunately you can't currently use the feed/`tf.placeholder()` mechanism to pass the result of one TensorFlow graph to another. We are investigating ways to make this easier, since it is a common confusion and feature request. For your exact program, it should be easy to solve this however. Simply move the [lines](https://gist.github.com/guivn/f7f753547f77a3b12992#file-cnn-py-L112) that create the input and replace the placeholders with them. Your program will then look something like:

```
with graph.as_default():

  # Input data.
  filename_and_label_tensor = tf.train.string_input_producer(['train.txt'], shuffle=True)
  data, label = parse_csv(filename_and_label_tensor)
  tf_train_dataset, tf_train_labels = tf.train.batch([data, label], batch_size, num_threads=4)

  # Rest of the model construction goes here....
```

Typically, if you want to pass another dataset through the same model—e.g. for evaluation—it's easiest to make another copy of the graph (perhaps sharing the same `tf.Variable` objects).